# Overriding a executable to add a default flag

Tags: configuration, alias, gmplayer

Here's my boggle. I use `gmplayer` to play all my videos. 99.9% of the time everything works fine but in that 1-in-1000 case, a video might be corrupted. `gmplayer` plays the video but it cries like an angry, hungry baby, popping up windows left, right and centre. In really bad videos this actually slows down the whole system as it spawns hundreds of error windows (compiz applies effects, etc). It also steals focus and occasionally cancels Christmas.

In the command-line `mplayer` these messages are just throw out to the command line. Using `mplayer`-proper might be an option if I can't use `gmplayer` but it's not quite as good for my needs.

I have found a workaround. If you add `-msglevel all=0` to the `gmplayer` call, errors are suppressed. Useless from a debug perspective but I'm not attempting to debug videos here, just watch them.

What I want to do is "alias" or "proxy" the `gmplayer` command so when you run `gmplayer` from the command line or by association, it actually runs `gmplayer -msglevel all=0`. I gather that just adding a bash alias won't work for associated (as in double clicking on a video in gnome) plays.

What are my options for hard-proxying the command. This only needs to work for one user but I'm open to system-wide changes too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set this option in one f the mplayer option files, this will then be the default behaviour. For system wide change /etc/mplayer/mpplayer.conf of just for that user create ~/.mplayer/mplayer.conf and put it in there.

Adding this to `~/.mplayer/mplayer.conf` works:

```
msglevel=all=0
```

Comment: any idea if it's the same config file for mplayer versus gmplayer?

Comment: It is. The code under the first paragraph is from me testing it.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution :-)

Comment: Config files should always be the first place to look. Nice one :-)

Comment: Doing this to mplayer also fixes gmplayer or any of the other front ends to mplayer. Things like gmplayer call mplayer in the background, and just display the video in a frame provided by the skin application.

Answer (score 3):

You could edit the `/usr/share/applications/mplayer.desktop` file to adujst the way the `gmplayer` command is called from the menu. Be sure to use `dpkg-divert` to make this change consistent locally:

```
$ sudo dpkg-divert /usr/share/applications/mplayer.desktop
```

This will tell `dpkg` to keep your modified version of the file in future package upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure how to complish this. other than writing a script that calls your executable with flags. But I know that in Eclipse that there is a `eclipse.ini` file in the same directory as the excutable that allows you to pass flags. Maybe looking into that you can write a similar file for `gmplayer`

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is probably the following:

1. rename the executable in `/usr/bin`
2. put in its place a script that will call the executable under the new name, that adds your argument.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   original-gmplayer -msglevel all=0 $@
   ```

Alternatively, you could put this script in the bin directory in your home, and make sure this bin directory is in your path (needs to be set system wide in order to work for applications that are not called from terminal)

Comment: Is there anything special that the script needs to do to pass along extra arguments? Say I replace `gmplayer` with my new proxy script, how can I pass, for example, `--help` or `-vo` onto the original executable? Or is this automatic?

Comment: The `$@` shell variable (or `$*`) contain all the arguments for the script. This means they are propagated to the call of gmplayer (obviously, gmplayer needs to be the new name for the original executable)

Comment: the variable to pass on arguments is `$@` the way you have your script written it allows the script as well to take arguments, and tack them on the `gmplayer` :)

Comment: Strange issue. When running it from the command line and passing the path to the video to my gmplayer executable, it worked fine but when double clicking a file it only gets the last part of the filename after the last space. In my case I was testing some Buffy I had ripped. A filename like: `/media/ned/tv/Buffy/Buffy The Vampire Slayer 7x05 Selfless.avi` was making gmplayer throw a file not found for `Selfless.avi`. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to insert the backslashes: 
`/media/ned/tv/Buffy/Buffy\ The\ Vampire\ Slayer\ 7x05\ Selfless.avi`

Comment: that is a problem with `$@` use this instead `$1` `$2` for your variables it doesn't handle spaces well. @icipriani he can't delimit them since they are being passed as a file name.

Comment: If you're going to replace anything in /usr/bin, use dpkg-divert to let dpkg know about it and make sure it doesn't get overridden when you upgrade the package.

Comment: If an update replaces the script, thinking it is the original executable, then what?

Comment: @Oli: the script is missing some quotes: `$@` should be `"$@"`. That's why it failed with an argument containing spaces. (@garbagecollector: your suggested use of `$1`, `$2`... is useless. The problem is the lack of quotes.)

Comment: @KeyboardMonkey: either follow Raphink's advice and use `dpkg-divert` to tell the packaging system that you now “own” `/usr/bin/gmplayer`, or better, put your script in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

As a different solution, use `smplayer` instead, which has the distinction of being actually maintained, and works great (which you cannot say of gmplayer).

Comment: `smplayer` is a different beast for a different type of person. I like gmplayer because it can fullscreen by default (remembers last setting), fullscreens on my second monitor (remembers last screen used), and its GUI is tiny enough that I can carry on doing things on my first monitor.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a symlink to your command. Create a command named mygmplayer, then verify where is your actual gmplayer command with whereis or which, then create a symlink to you command.
Here an example

```
 $ echo '#!/bin/bash' > /home/user/mygmplayer
 $ echo "gmplayer -msglevel all=0" >> /home/user/mygmplayer
 $ chmod a+x mygmplayer
 $ which gmplayer
 /usr/bin/gmplayer
 $ sudo mv /usr/bin/gmplayer /usr/bin/gmplayer.old
 $ sudo ln -s /home/user/mygmplayer /usr/bin/gmplayer
```

Bye.

Comment: The last part needs to be done as `root`, surely?

Comment: Yes, why not? I will edit the post

Comment: This would be better done with a bash alias in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Wait... did you actually test what you've posted? You want to replace /usr/bin/gmplayer with a symlink to a script that calls gmplayer... where will it find it?

Comment: No you haven't ;-) You're still calling gmplayer instead of gmplayer.old in your script, and your symlink is of no use at all.
It's generally not a good idea to advocate modifying anything in /usr/bin (unless you package it with Conflicts).

Comment: Rahink is right, rather avoid messing around in /usr/bin.

Comment: Yes, he is right about /usr/bin, but the ln command works. He has not tested my code, it works. The ln man says:
`ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`
It is clear that if the target link does not exists (I have just modified the name of gmplayer to gmplayer.old), then the ln command does the right thing. Thank you for suggestion.